# ... regarding the advertised position of a researcher in the ... department

Tags: letter-writing

Which of the following should I use:

> I'm writing to you regarding the advertised position **of** a researcher in the ... department
>
> I'm writing to you regarding the advertised position **for** a researcher in the ... department

I'm also interested in which of the following is more appropriate in letter writing to Europeans:

> ... regarding the advertised **vacancy**
>
> ... regarding the advertised **position**

Comment: Position as a researcher? Position of researcher

Comment: @mplungjan - Please elaborate. What did you mean?

Comment: When you say *Europeans*, you mean as distinct from whom: Australians, Indians, Africans, ...?

Comment: I meant: either "position as a researcher" or "the position of researcher" are valid. _position for_ or _of a_ do not sound right

Comment: But the *position* is for a researcher to occupy. I'd be quite happy with *for*.

Comment: As a European (English, currently in the USA) either of the *of/for* would be acceptable. For the 2nd part, I would consider **position**, as *vacancy* would seem to imply you are replacing someone, which is not necessarily the case. (as it's only my opinion and can't be supported by references, I leave this as a comment, and not an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "of a researcher" sounds to me that the position is being offered by a researcher (e.g. for a secretary to the researcher). When you say "for a researcher" then it's clear that it is a research position.

I think the whole thing would sound stronger if you just said "Regarding the advertised research position in the X department, . . . "

Comment: Yes, I like that form.